# Google App Engine Launcher slow app response

Tags: python, windows, google-app-engine, launcher

When I try to access a local app from localhost:8080 using the GAE launcher, it takes about 42 seconds for a response every time very consistently.  Even for the simplest apps like the hello world tutorial. This happens in chrome, firefox, and IE. I'll make the request and watch the log and 42 seconds later I will get the "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 426 in the log file.  I ran the launcher through winpdb and paused the code several times during the wait.  I always found myself in _Condition.wait() on the while True: line in threading.py.  In GAE, this traced back to either _BackgroundTaskScheduler._Wait() in taskqueue_stub.py or AutoScalingServer._loop_adjusting_instances() in server.py.  Maybe there is a problem acquiring some lock.

My current setup:
GAE 1.8.1
Windows 7 64-bit
Python 2.7.5 64-bit (python.org)

This problem does not exist if I use old_dev_appserver.py.  I get an instant response using the older appserver.